# Ext.String.escape

Tags: string, extjs

For a string like following:

Sencha's string utility is "good"

Ext.String.escape will convert it to following:

Sencha\\'s string utility is \"good\"

Why it adds double backslash on apostrophe vs single backslash on inverted comma.

What end up happening is when I displayed the string it showed up like this:

Sencha\'s string utility is "good"

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Ext.String.escape('Sencha\'s string utility is "good"').replace(/\\/,'');
// Output: Sencha's string utility is "good"
```